# Sorting in NSHomeDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I have this code to save images in my app

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2013_%d_a_%d",count,indexToInsert];
        NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:fileName]];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToAdd);
        [imageData writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

in my log I see this:

```
    "2013_10_a_1",
    "2013_1_a_1",
    "2013_2_a_1",
    "2013_3_a_1",
    "2013_4_a_1",
    "2013_5_a_1",
    "2013_6_a_1",
    "2013_7_a_1",
    "2013_8_a_1",
    "2013_9_a_1"
```

why "2013_10_1" is on the top? it's in position 0, I want it at position 9 (10 elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the underscore character `_` ([ascii code](http://www.ascii-code.com) 95) is sorted after any number character (ascii codes 48 to 57).

Change the output filename to include leading zero and you won't need to mess with sorting issues:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2013_%03d_a_%d",count,indexToInsert];
```

Will output:

```
"2013_001_a_1",
"2013_002_a_1",
"2013_003_a_1",
"2013_004_a_1",
"2013_005_a_1",
"2013_006_a_1",
"2013_007_a_1",
"2013_008_a_1",
"2013_009_a_1",
"2013_010_a_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings contain numbers so you need to do a numeric sort, not a plain string sort. For this, use the `compare:options:` method on `NSString` with an option of `NSNumericSearch`.